# NSDateFormatter format displaying incorrect format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have the date (as an `NSString`) of the format:

```
20120508T224500Z
```

I am trying to use `NSDateFormatter` to create an `NSDate` from the string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

But this parses/formats the NSDate incorrectly.

I am trying to get the format:

```
4:45 PM 5/8/2012
```

How can I use the date formatter `yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ` to get this format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must single quote the 'T' and 'Z' in the string: `20120508T224500Z`

See [unicode date formatting](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns) for formatting information.

Example:

```
NSString *dateString = @"20120508T224500Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];  
NSLog(@"dateFromString: %@", dateFromString);

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:m a M/d/yyyy"];
NSString *newDataString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
NSLog(@"newDataString: %@", newDataString);
```

NSLog output:

> dateFromString: 2012-05-09 02:45:00 +0000
>   newDataString: 10:45 PM 5/8/2012

Note that NSLog used the NSDate description method and displays the date/time in local time.
Use `- (void)setTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)tz` to create the string in a different timezone.